# Struggling to connect main method to java classes

Tags: java, class, methods

here is my first class client

```
package hwch33;
import java.net.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.*;


public class Client extends Application {
// IO streams 
DataOutputStream toServer = null; 
DataInputStream fromServer = null; 

@Override // Override the start method in the Application class 
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
 // Panel p to hold the label and text field 
  BorderPane paneForTextField = new BorderPane();
  paneForTextField.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5)); 
  paneForTextField.setStyle("-fx-border-color: green");
  paneForTextField.setLeft(new Label("Enter a radius: "));

  TextField tf = new TextField();
  tf.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
  paneForTextField.setCenter(tf);

  BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();
  // Text area to display contents 
  TextArea ta = new TextArea();
  mainPane.setCenter(new ScrollPane(ta));
  mainPane.setTop(paneForTextField);

  // Create a scene and place it in the stage 
  Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 450, 200);
  primaryStage.setTitle("Client"); // Set the stage title 
  primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage 
  primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage 

  tf.setOnAction(e -> {
    try {
      // Get the radius from the text field 
      double radius = Double.parseDouble(tf.getText().trim());

      // Send the radius to the server
      toServer.writeDouble(radius);
      toServer.flush();

      // Get area from the server 
      double area = fromServer.readDouble();

      // Display to the text area 
      ta.appendText("Radius is " + radius + "\n");
      ta.appendText("Area received from the server is " 
        + area + '\n');
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      System.err.println(ex);
    }
  });

  try {
    // Create a socket to connect to the server 
    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8000); 
    //Socket socket = new Socket("130.254.204.36", 8000); 
    //Socket socket = new Socket("drake.Armstrong.edu", 8000); 

    // Create an input stream to receive data from the server 
    fromServer = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); 

    // Create an output stream to send data to the server 
    toServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); 
  }
  catch (IOException ex) {
    ta.appendText(ex.toString() + '\n');
  }
 }
 }
```

here is my second class server

```
 package hwch33;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.*;
 import java.util.Date;
 import javafx.application.Application;
 import javafx.application.Platform;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
 import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
 import javafx.stage.Stage;


 public class Server extends Application {

 /**
 *
 * @param primaryStage
 */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
 // Text area for displaying contents 
    TextArea ta = new TextArea();

    // Create a scene and place it in the stage 
    Scene scene = new Scene(new ScrollPane(ta), 450, 200);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Server"); // Set the stage title 
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage 
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage 

    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
        // Create a server socket 
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000); 
            Platform.runLater(() ->
            ta.appendText("Server started at " + new Date() + '\n'));


            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); 

            DataInputStream inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(
                socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream outputToClient = new DataOutputStream(
                socket.getOutputStream());

            while (true) {
                double radius = inputFromClient.readDouble(); 
                double area = radius * radius * Math.PI;
                outputToClient.writeDouble(area); 

                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    ta.appendText("Radius received from client: " 
                      + radius + '\n');
                    ta.appendText("Area is: " + area + '\n'); 
                });
            }
        }
            catch(IOException ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();
            }
          }).start();
         }
        }
```

Here is where i need to add the code to make it all work

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project 
 Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package hwch33;





/**
*
* @author 
*/
public class HWCH33 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */



 public static void main(String[] args) {        

}



}
```

Not sure how to construct a main from here.
Ive been trying to form one but cannot get it right. I either get static error or it just doesnt work at all.
Any help is appreciated. Did not include any of my previous attempts because they are useless and I got rid of them all.

Comment: What do you mean by `construct a main`? Do you mean a main void? `public static void main(String[] args){}`?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I mean. Both of those sets of code are seperate class files.

Comment: What do you mean by `connect` them? What error do you get?

Comment: Im just struggling to get them to run. I suppose run is a better word to use than connect. They are supposed to return with the area.

Comment: Ive tried doing Client.start(primaryStage);

Comment: Is where you call `Client.start(primaryStage);` and the primaryStage variable both static or both not static? Is where you call `Client.start(primaryStage);` accessible?

Comment: I will add my third file to the main question thread to give you a better understanding.

Comment: I added my third file which has to get the code to run. They all sit in the same folder

Comment: There is no code in the main method that runs your thread.

Comment: Thats what I am trying to figure out. The code that is supposed to go in there.

Comment: <This is an XY problem.> This is where you'd add `Client.start(primaryStage);`

Comment: Okay i tried that and then created a local variable for primary stage and am getting a static error.

Comment: Show me the **specific error.** Copy and paste it directly from your compiler. Either A) Make primaryStage static or B) Make a variable of type class (whatever created the primaryStage variable) and do variable.primaryStage.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Stage primaryStage = null;
        Client.start(primaryStage);
    }

Comment: Then it says non static method start(Stage) cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Then **DON'T** call `start(Stage)` from that method. Use another non-static method that exists purely to call the primaryStage variable. Who knows. Do something.

Answer (score 0):

If the error is that a non-static variable is not compatible with a static method or something along those lines, just omit the word "static" from public static void main(String[] args){}.

Comment: You need the main method to be public and static to work, otherwise, the Java Virtual Machine won't be able to run your program.